# Generate a Random Word in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am trying to explore the Swift programming language. I was searching through the Swift API and I found the `UIReferenceLibraryViewController` class. I found the method that returns a bool value if a word is real or not (`.dictionaryHasDefinitionForTerm`) and I also looked for a method that can return a random word.

Sadly, this method does not seem to exist. I realize that I can explore 3rd party APIs, however I prefer to stay away from them if possible.

I thought that maybe I could go through random permutations of all letters and then check if they form a real word, but this seems... well... stupid.

Does anybody know of a way to generate a random word?

I also do not want to manually make a long list of thousands of words because I fear a memory error. I want to try to also learn some syntax and new methods, not how to navigate lists.

Comment: "I also do not want to make a long list of thousands of words" So you don't know how to do this but you get to rule out ways of doing it? How do you imagine you can pick a random _anything_ if you don't start with a collection of that thing? A card trick involving a random card from a deck requires a deck! If I hold out my empty hand and say "pick a card, any card", how will you do it?

Comment: Well, you would start grabbing random things around the room, check if they're a card, and if they're not keep going... But we've eliminated that as an option too.

Comment: Copy `/usr/share/dict/words` from your mac to your app's bundle and use that.

Comment: @JAL That's very nice!

Comment: Having a long list of words will cause a memory error, no?

Comment: @JAL I will check if your answer works and then accept it in a couple of days. I have been having some issues with my computer and it should be fixed in 3 days max. Sorry for the delay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My `/usr/share/dict/words` file is a symbolic link to `/usr/share/dict/words/web2`, Webster's Second International Dictionary from 1934.  The file is only 2.4mb, so you shouldn't see too much of a performance hit loading the entire contents into memory.

Here's a small Swift 3.0 snippet I wrote to load a random word from the dictionary file.  Remember to copy the file to your Application's bundle before running.

```
if let wordsFilePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "web2", ofType: nil) {
    do {
        let wordsString = try String(contentsOfFile: wordsFilePath)

        let wordLines = wordsString.components(separatedBy: .newlines)

        let randomLine = wordLines[numericCast(arc4random_uniform(numericCast(wordLines.count)))]

        print(randomLine)

    } catch { // contentsOfFile throws an error
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Swift 2.2:

```
if let wordsFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("web2", ofType: nil) {
    do {
        let wordsString = try String(contentsOfFile: wordsFilePath)

        let wordLines = wordsString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())

        let randomLine = wordLines[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wordLines.count)))]

        print(randomLine)

    } catch { // contentsOfFile throws an error
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Swift 1.2 snippet:

```
if let wordsFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("web2", ofType: nil) {

    var error: NSError?

    if let wordsString = String(contentsOfFile: wordsFilePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) {

        if error != nil {
            // String(contentsOfFile: ...) failed
            println("Error: \(error)")
        } else {
            let wordLines = wordsString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())

            let randomLine = wordLines[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wordLines.count)))]

            print(randomLine)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're referring to the `web2` wordlist file right?  Anywhere in your project directory should be fine, make sure you copy it to your target and the file is listed under "Copy Bundle Resources."

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to check this project. A guy have already done the following for you!

**LoremSwiftum**

> LoremSwiftum is a lightweight lorem ipsum generator for iOS written in Swift. It supports generating texts in different formats (words, sentences, paragraphs), miscellaneous data (names, URLs, dates etc.) and placeholder images for iOS (UIImage). This is a reimplementation of the project LoremIpsum written in Objective-C.

https://github.com/lukaskubanek/LoremSwiftum

This project has only single swift file.( ~300 lines)
Therefore, I think reading the file will help you.

https://github.com/lukaskubanek/LoremSwiftum/blob/master/Sources/LoremSwiftum.swift

Answer (score 3):

Try this snippet

```
struct RandomWordGenerator {
    private let words: [String]
    
    func ranged(_ range: ClosedRange<Int>) -> RandomWordGenerator {
        RandomWordGenerator(words: words.filter { range.contains($0.count) })
    }
}

extension RandomWordGenerator: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    public func next() -> String? {
        words.randomElement()
    }
}

extension RandomWordGenerator {
    init() throws {
        let file = try String(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/share/dict/words"))
        self.init(words: file.components(separatedBy: "\n"))
    }
}

// usage example:
let random = try! RandomWordGenerator()
print(random.next()!)
print("3 randoms: \(random.prefix(3).joined(separator: ", "))")
print("Another 3 randoms: \(random.prefix(3).joined(separator: ", "))")
```

Comment: how do you run this. trying to init a Player instance, where name: is a random word. 

`struct Player {
    let name: String
    let number: Int

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = "\(RandomWordGenerator())"
        number = Int.random(in: 1...99)
    }
}
//error: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled`

Comment: RandomWordGenerator here is just a sequence.
Will extend my snippet

Answer (score 2):

Get random word of length 5.

```
func randomWord() -> String
    {
        var x = "";
        for _ in 0..<5{
            let string = String(format: "%c", Int.random(in: 97..<123)) as String
            x+=string
        }
        return x
     }
```

Comment: This answer does not have all the upvotes it deserves.

Answer (score 0):

Above code will create the paragraph text  which can be used to set in label , textview ..

```
func randomPargraph(pargraph : Int = 40 ) -> String{
        var global = ""
        
        for _ in 0..<(Int.random(in: 2..<pargraph)) {
            
            var x = "";
            for _ in 0..<Int.random(in: 2..<15){
                let string = String(format: "%c", Int.random(in: 97..<123)) as String
                x+=string
            }
            global = global +  " " + x
        }
        
     
        
        return global
     }
```