# Random word(Meaningful) generation

Tags: ios, swift, words

I am trying to build a game in SpriteKit. which I planned to create some random words. I found some links but unfortunately, I am not able to figure out a solution.
Does anybody know of a way to generate a random word?

Comment: You can check the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31212805/2776008

Comment: Don't generate a random word,  select it from an array.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would probably be to just make an Array of accepted random words and pick a random element.

`let words = ["One", "Fish", "Two", "Fishes", "Red", "Blue"]`

**Swift 4.2**: `let word = words.randomElement()`

**Pre-Swift 4.2** [Look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003191/pick-a-random-element-from-an-array)

Comment: Thanks for your response.